# Why would Gmail signature settings/setup be different for different email addresses?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I have two Gmail addresses, one personal `@gmail.com` address, and one for work that is `@mywork'sURL.com`. When adding or changing my signature, I noticed that for my personal Gmail address there are more options for inserting photographs compared to the work Gmail. For the personal account, I can upload a photo directly or through Google Drive. For the work account, I'm stuck with the option of linking to an image that needs to be hosted somewhere online. That is the only option that shows up when I try to insert photo, even though I get three different options when I try doing the same thing on my personal Gmail.

In addition to that issue, the signature that I'm using works fine on my personal Gmail, however, when I tried to use that exact same signature on the work Gmail, I get the error message that says that my signature is too long.

Has anyone else ran into these issues with Gmail before?

If so, what solution/s worked for you?

Comment: "Why" questions don't generally do well on Stack Exchange sites. The only people who can really answer are the ones who designed it that way, and they're not active here.

Answer (score 0):

Your personal email is using the free version of gmail whereas your company is paying for google apps (that's how the domain is their own instead of @gmail).

I'm not sure why the settings are set up differently but you should contact support for google apps, maybe they can be changed. I wonder if your admin can adjust limitations on signatures etc.

Answer (score 0):

Company email addresses administered through Gmail will be part of the company's GSuite users.  Your company GSuite administrator can change the default configuration through the administrator UI.  They likely limited images in order to limit email size, and maybe because they want you to use a company approved image only.  Plus the business GMail is compatible with other email clients like Outlook -- so it may be compatibility that is limiting what that configuration can accept.